# Flutter ExpansionTile arrow on left instead of right?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to have the rotating expansion arrow on a Flutter ExpansionTile widget as leading rather than trailing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just copy the [source code of the widget](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/expansion_tile.dart) and create your own customized version.

Comment: I have written an extension of the ExpansionTile based on the source code. Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047537/what-should-i-do-if-the-nodes-of-a-list-have-content-that-should-be-displayed-wh

Answer (score 6):

```
const ExpansionTile(
          title: Text('ExpansionTile 3'),
          subtitle: Text('Leading expansion arrow icon'),
          controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 3')),
          ],
        ),
```

The controlAffinity property helps you put it in the leading position, to place it before the title

Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html

Comment: mine is error when i add this code: controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.leading,