# Place the ExpansionTile arrow on the left side?

Tags: flutter

What is the best way to place the arrow of an `ExpansionTile` on the left side instead of on the right side?

I know there is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51037646/flutter-expansiontile-arrow-on-left-instead-of-right), but the accepted answer (to simply copy the source code of `ExpansionTile` and modify it) is more of a quick-and-dirty hack than a real solution IMHO.

Can this be done in a more elegant way?

Comment: what about making the direction of this expansion tile RTL, this will place your arrow in the left, this a hacky solution  I know, but it is better than modifying the source code