# What should I do if the nodes of a multlevel list have content that should be displayed when clicked? (Advanced ExpansionTile)

Tags: flutter

For a flutter project I needed a tree structure in which when clicking on a node, not only the entries below it are displayed, but - as with the file manager in Windows - also the content: On a smartphone as a new screen and on a tablet as an additional area to the right of the list. 
Unfortunately, the standard ExpansionTile does not have this capability.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm a newcomer to Flutter, I first looked at the source code and tried to understand the most important parts (I'm still at it ;-). Then I made the following changes:

1. A property 'AlignOpener' now decides whether the open/close icon is displayed on the left or right.
2. I added the properties 'onTap' and 'onLongPress' as callback. Once one of these properties is assigned in the calling widget, the '_isInAdvancedMode' property is set to true and an IconButton is inserted as leading or trailing. 
   Clicking this button will open/close the directory tree. A click on the remaining part is forwarded to the calling widget via callback.
3. Finally, I added a property 'indentListTile' to control the indent of each layer.

If none of the properties are assigned, the AvancedExpansionTile behaves like the standard ExpansionTile.

Since I'm a newbie, there's still a lot of uncertainty as to whether the code is really correct. As far as I can see, it works, but I would be happy if experienced developers among you could check the code and make suggestions for improvements if necessary.
Maybe the code solves a problem that others also had?

Her is the code:

master_list_item.dart

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class ItemMaster {
  ItemMaster(
      {this.id,
      @required this.title,
      this.subtitle,
      this.children = const <ItemMaster>[]});

  final int id;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;
  final List<ItemMaster> children;
}
```

master_list.dart

```
import 'master_list_item.dart';

class MasterList {
  List<ItemMaster> get items {
    return _items;
  }

  final List<ItemMaster> _items = <ItemMaster>[
    ItemMaster(
      title: 'Chapter Master List',
      id: 1,
      children: <ItemMaster>[
        ItemMaster(
          title: 'Scene A0',
          id: 2,
          children: <ItemMaster>[
            ItemMaster(title: 'Item A0.1', id: 3),
            ItemMaster(title: 'Item A0.2', id: 4),
            ItemMaster(title: 'Item A0.3', id: 5),
          ],
        ),
        ItemMaster(title: 'Scene A1', id: 6),
        ItemMaster(title: 'Scene A2', id: 7),
      ],
    ),
    ItemMaster(
      title: 'Chapter B',
      id: 8,
      children: <ItemMaster>[
        ItemMaster(title: 'Scene B0', id: 9),
        ItemMaster(title: 'Scene B1', id: 10),
      ],
    ),
    ItemMaster(
      title: 'Chapter C',
      id: 11,
      children: <ItemMaster>[
        ItemMaster(title: 'Scene C0', id: 12),
        ItemMaster(title: 'Scene C1', id: 13),
        ItemMaster(
          title: 'Scene C2',
          id: 14,
          children: <ItemMaster>[
            ItemMaster(title: 'Item C2.0', id: 15),
            ItemMaster(title: 'Item C2.1', id: 16),
            ItemMaster(title: 'Item C2.2', id: 17),
            ItemMaster(title: 'Item C2.3', id: 18),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ];
}
```

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'advanced_expansion_tile.dart';
import 'master_list_item.dart';
import 'master_list.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<ItemMaster> items;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    items = MasterList().items;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: items.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, int index) => MasterListEntry(items[index]),
        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MasterListEntry extends StatelessWidget {
  const MasterListEntry(this.entry);

  final ItemMaster entry;

  Widget _buildTiles(ItemMaster root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty)
      return ListTile(
        title: Text(root.title),
        onTap: () => print("onTap listTile"),
      );
    return AdvancedExpansionTile(
      key: PageStorageKey<ItemMaster>(root),
      title: Text(root.title),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
      onTap: () => print("onTap AdvancedExpansionTile"),
      alignOpener: AlignOpener.Right,
      indentListTile: 15.0,
//      isInAdvancedMode: true,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

advanced_expansion_tile.dart (based on the source code from the Flutter team)

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Duration _kExpand = Duration(milliseconds: 200);
enum AlignOpener { Left, Right }

class AdvancedExpansionTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const AdvancedExpansionTile({
    Key key,
    this.leading,
    this.trailing,
    @required this.title,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.onExpansionChanged,
    this.onTap,
    this.onLongPress,
    this.alignOpener,
    this.indentListTile,
    this.children = const <Widget>[],
    this.initiallyExpanded = false,
  })  : assert(initiallyExpanded != null),
        super(key: key);

  /// A widget to display before the title.
  ///
  /// Typically a [CircleAvatar] widget.
  final Widget leading;

  /// The primary content of the list item.
  ///
  /// Typically a [Text] widget.
  final Widget title;

  /// Called when the tile expands or collapses.
  ///
  /// When the tile starts expanding, this function is called with the value
  /// true. When the tile starts collapsing, this function is called with
  /// the value false.
  final ValueChanged<bool> onExpansionChanged;

  /// The widgets that are displayed when the tile expands.
  ///
  /// Typically [ListTile] widgets.
  final List<Widget> children;

  /// The color to display behind the sublist when expanded.
  final Color backgroundColor;

  /// Specifies if the list tile is initially expanded (true) or collapsed (false, the default).
  final bool initiallyExpanded;

  /// A widget to display instead of a rotating arrow icon.
  final Widget trailing;

  /// A callback for onTap and onLongPress on the listTile
  final GestureTapCallback onTap;
  final GestureLongPressCallback onLongPress;

  /// The side where the Open/Close-Icon/IconButton will be placed
  final AlignOpener alignOpener;

  /// indent of listTile (left)
  final indentListTile;

  @override
  _AdvancedExpansionTileState createState() => _AdvancedExpansionTileState();
}

class _AdvancedExpansionTileState extends State<AdvancedExpansionTile>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  static final Animatable<double> _easeOutTween =
      CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeOut);
  static final Animatable<double> _easeInTween =
      CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn);
  static final Animatable<double> _halfTween =
      Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 0.5);

  final ColorTween _borderColorTween = ColorTween();
  final ColorTween _headerColorTween = ColorTween();
  final ColorTween _iconColorTween = ColorTween();
  final ColorTween _backgroundColorTween = ColorTween();

  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation<double> _iconTurns;
  Animation<double> _heightFactor;
  Animation<Color> _borderColor;
  Animation<Color> _headerColor;
  Animation<Color> _iconColor;
  Animation<Color> _backgroundColor;

  bool _isExpanded = false;

  /// If set to true an IconButton will be created. This button will open/close the children
  bool _isInAdvancedMode;
  AlignOpener _alignOpener;
  double _indentListTile;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(duration: _kExpand, vsync: this);
    _heightFactor = _controller.drive(_easeInTween);
    _iconTurns = _controller.drive(_halfTween.chain(_easeInTween));
    _borderColor = _controller.drive(_borderColorTween.chain(_easeOutTween));
    _headerColor = _controller.drive(_headerColorTween.chain(_easeInTween));
    _iconColor = _controller.drive(_iconColorTween.chain(_easeInTween));
    _backgroundColor =
        _controller.drive(_backgroundColorTween.chain(_easeOutTween));

    _isExpanded =
        PageStorage.of(context)?.readState(context) ?? widget.initiallyExpanded;
    if (_isExpanded) _controller.value = 1.0;

    /// OnTap or onLongPress are handled in the calling widget --> AdvancedExpansionTile is in Advanced Mode
    if (widget.onTap != null || widget.onLongPress != null) {
      _isInAdvancedMode = true;
    } else {
      _isInAdvancedMode = false;
    }

    /// fallback to standard behaviour if aligning isn't set
    _alignOpener = widget.alignOpener ?? AlignOpener.Right;

    /// if no indent is set the indent will be 0.0
    _indentListTile = widget.indentListTile ?? 0.0;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleTap() {
    setState(() {
      _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
      if (_isExpanded) {
        _controller.forward();
      } else {
        _controller.reverse().then<void>((void value) {
          if (!mounted) return;
          setState(() {
            // Rebuild without widget.children.
          });
        });
      }
      PageStorage.of(context)?.writeState(context, _isExpanded);
    });
    if (widget.onExpansionChanged != null)
      widget.onExpansionChanged(_isExpanded);
  }

  Widget _buildChildren(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    final Color borderSideColor = _borderColor.value ?? Colors.transparent;

    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: _backgroundColor.value ?? Colors.transparent,
        border: Border(
          top: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
          bottom: BorderSide(color: borderSideColor),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTileTheme.merge(
            iconColor: _iconColor.value,
            textColor: _headerColor.value,
            child: ListTile(
              onTap: () {
                _isInAdvancedMode ? widget.onTap() : _handleTap();
              }, // in AdvancedMode a callback will handle the gesture inside the calling widget

              onLongPress: () {
                _isInAdvancedMode ? widget.onLongPress() : _handleTap();
              }, // in AdvancedMode a callback will handle the gesture inside the calling widget
              leading: getLeading(),
              title: widget.title,
              trailing: getTrailing(),
            ),
          ),
          ClipRect(
              child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: _indentListTile), // set the indent
            child: Align(
              heightFactor: _heightFactor.value,
              child: child,
            ),
          )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    _borderColorTween..end = theme.dividerColor;
    _headerColorTween
      ..begin = theme.textTheme.subhead.color
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _iconColorTween
      ..begin = theme.unselectedWidgetColor
      ..end = theme.accentColor;
    _backgroundColorTween..end = widget.backgroundColor;
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool closed = !_isExpanded && _controller.isDismissed;
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller.view,
      builder: _buildChildren,
      child: closed ? null : Column(children: widget.children),
    );
  }

  /// A method to decide what will be shown in the leading part of the lisTile
  getLeading() {
    if (_alignOpener.toString() == AlignOpener.Left.toString() &&
        _isInAdvancedMode == true) {
      return buildIcon(); //IconButton will be created
    } else if (_alignOpener.toString() == AlignOpener.Left.toString() &&
        _isInAdvancedMode == false) {
      return widget.leading ??
          RotationTransition(
            turns: _iconTurns,
            child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
          );
    } else {
      return widget.leading;
    }
  }

  /// A method to decide what will be shown in the trailing part of the lisTile
  getTrailing() {
    if (_alignOpener.toString() == AlignOpener.Right.toString() &&
        _isInAdvancedMode == true) {
      return buildIcon(); //IconButton will be created
    } else if (_alignOpener.toString() == AlignOpener.Right.toString() &&
        _isInAdvancedMode == false) {
      return widget.trailing ??
          RotationTransition(
            turns: _iconTurns,
            child: const Icon(Icons.expand_more),
          );
    } else {
      return widget.leading;
    }
  }

  /// A widget to build the IconButton for the leading or trailing part of the listTile
  Widget buildIcon() {
    return Container(
        child: RotationTransition(
      turns: _iconTurns,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.expand_more),
        onPressed: () {
          _handleTap();
          //toDo: open/close is working but not the animation
        },
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```